# Using unknown amount of buttons

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

If I had a lot of buttons on one page how could I find when a specific button is pressed?

In my example I am using a for loop with a variable length to print out an order in my system. Each order has 2 buttons "Delete Order" - which deletes the order, and "Update Order" - which changes the order status from "not done" to "ready for pick up".

How can I know when a specific one of these buttons are pressed. It would not be feasible to use an if elseif elseif, etc. as I have seen in other solutions.

This is in my routes.py file:

```
@app.route('/admin/orders', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def orders():
    if request.method == "POST":
        for order in system.orders:
            if request.form["status"] == str(order.orderID):
                order.setOrderStatus("ready for pick-up")
                return redirect(url_for('orders'))
            if request.form["delete"] == str(order.orderID):
                order.deleteOrder(order.currOrder)
                return redirect(url_for('orders'))
    return render_template("orders.html", system = system)
```

This is in my html/jinja file for order.html:

```
<form action="POST">
{% for order in system.orders %}
    <p style="white-space: pre; font-size: 30px;">{{order.print}}

    <button type = "submit" name="status" class="choice" value="{{order.orderID}}" style = "margin:10px">Change Status</button>

    <button type = "submit" name="delete" class="choice" value="{{order.orderID}}" style = "margin:10px;">Delete Order</button>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

I want to be able to click a button and be taken to the same page with the updated order status or the order deleted. I am currently getting put to a page with POST?status=1 at the end of the URL and a black page with only the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="POST">
```

should be:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness: You can use the HTML input [formaction](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_formaction.asp) attribute to submit to different urls depending on the button that has been pressed. This way you can skip the server-side logic completely. In the above example it would look something like this:

```
{% for order in system.orders %}
<p style="white-space: pre; font-size: 30px;">{{order.print}}
    <button type="submit" formaction="{{ url_for('insert_route', id=order.id) }}" class="choice" name="{{order.orderID}}CS" style = "margin:10px">Change Status</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="{{ url_for('delete_route', id=order.id) }}" class="choice" name="{{order.orderID}}DO" style = "margin:10px; margin-right:30px;">Delete Order</button>
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to do something like this. replace #do not know what to fill in here with this:

```
if request.method == "POST":

    if request.form["submit"] == "change_status":
        return redirect(url_for('<insert route>'))

    if request.form["submit"] == "delete_order":
        return redirect(url_for('<insert route>'))
```

and add a value to your buttons in the template and wrap it in form tags if that is not already the case.

```
<button type="submit" class="choice" name="{{order.orderID}}CS" style = "margin:10px" value = "change_status">Change Status</button>
<button type="submit" class="choice" name="{{order.orderID}}DO" style = "margin:10px; margin-right:30px;" value = "delete_order">Delete Order</button>
```